# Xamarin forms: Issue using content view

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, freshmvvm

I am using Xamarin forms with FreshMvvm framework. I am creating pages in Xaml. I want to use content view to resume in multiple pages.

**ContentView.xaml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
        x:Class="Coc.Core.ContentsView">
    <ContentView.Content>
        <StackLayout BackgroundColor="Silver"> 
            <SearchBar Placeholder="Search"  BackgroundColor="Olive"  />
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentView.Content>
</ContentView>
```

**ContentView.xaml,cs:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace Coc.Core
{
    public partial class ContentsView : ContentView
    {
        public ContentsView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

**Homepage.xaml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
        x:Class="Coc.Core.StartUpPage" 
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Coc.Core;assembly=Coc.Core"
        Title ="Home">
    <ContentPage.Content> 
        <StackLayout BackgroundColor="Silver" Spacing="30"  Padding ="20,50,20,10" > 
            <Image  />
            <SearchBar Placeholder="Search" />
            <Label Text="Hello" TextColor="Red" Style="{StaticResource infoLabelStyle}"/> 
            <local:ContentsView />
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

**Homepage.xaml.cs:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using FreshMvvm;c
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace Coc.Core
{
    public partial class StartUpPage : ContentPage
    {
        public StartUpPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

    }
}
```

When I am trying to use contentsView in a page homepage, I am getting an error : Could not load file or assembly coc.core or one of its assembly.

Can anyone advice, if anything is wrong in my code.

Thanks.

Comment: is "Coc.Core" the actual name of the PCL assembly where your view resides?

Comment: Yes. It is the namespace

Comment: No, not the namespace.  The actual name of the DLL your project creates.  Look at "Assembly Name" in the Project Options under Build -> Output

Comment: It was Coc. Now I changed assembly name in homepage.xml. Now its working. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please change into as following :

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Coc.Core;assembly=Coc.Core"
    x:Class="Coc.Core.StartUpPage" 
    Title ="Home">
```

Answer (score 1):

It probably means your assembly name is wrong. Instead of trying to correct it, you can just ignore it, as it seems that you're referencing the current assembly.

So your `HomePage.xaml` could look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
    x:Class="Coc.Core.StartUpPage" 
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Coc.Core"
    Title ="Home">
```